# Is it better do define subclasses or have a table with arguments to feed a constructor?

Tags: inheritance, optimization, lookup-tables

Let's say I am making the usual case of a bank program. In this program, I would like to apply different arguments depending on the type of customer that is coming to the bank. Arguments should be fixed depending on the type of customer that enters the bank. For example, CustomerA is a small business owner and the bank has a set of parameters that will offer to this customer (the parameters are decided by the bank without following a mathematical formula). He can borrow x amount of money and he has a y interest rate, bla, bla, bla. CustomerB is a private citizen and he will have a different set of parameters.

Now, my question is: to implement such a program is it better to load an LUT to read said parameters (in the constructor for example) or to create a subclass for each of the types of customer? My guess is that the LUT case is more computing expensive but easier to implement and change while the subclass system is more annoying to implement but less computationally expensive. Does it change depending on the language?

Comment: To me, the real question is not how you consume the parameters/arguments, but how you supply them. What is your plan for that side of the problem?

Comment: I guess that would be linked to the previous decision. If you need to create a new object of the class when using a LUT you could do something like: c = Customer("shop_owner"). While for the subclass you would have to implement logic to find the correct subclass before using it.
However that doesn't really answer which approach is more efficient. The LUT case is more direct but the program still has to search in the LUT before creating the object while the subclass needs a logic check before creating the object.